# cannot control the width of div and how can I fix it?(html)

Tags: html, css

Here is html and CSS code:

```css
.d1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16pt;
  width: 30px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
</div>
```

the text breaks through the width of div even though I have set

```
display:inline-block
```

Are there any methods that makes the text within the width of div?

Comment: add `word-wrap: normal;` into your given css rule

Answer (score 3):

Set your CSS to have `word-wrap` to `break-word`.

```css
.d1{
display:inline-block;
font-size:16pt;
width:30px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21; 
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
testingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, it works!
I will google "word-wrap: break-word;" for more details.
It really helps me, Thank you so much!